# Disconnected Network Drive Issue After mounting FTP Drive

Tags: c++

I have created a Driver for FTP mounting but when i mount any folder it comes as "Disconnected Network Drive " , I am able to see the contents of the mounted folder and when i restart my system that mounted drive goes off. When i look into net use command for system CIFS(SMB) moiunting it works fine i dont know what i am missing in my driver code . I am not able to find any good document on net use also which describes how it is implemented and how it works . My application is in C++.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You need a helper network redirector user-mode DLL for Explorer .

Comment: ...and exactly how does this answer OP's question?

Comment: @Andre and am I supposed to provide the source code of such DLL (this is possible of course, as part of our products' source code)? The OP is asking for knowledge of how this is done. Now he knows what exactly to look for.

Comment: Any sample code for not getting mounted drive as "Disconnected Network Drive".